# one ssl certificate for multiple sites?

Tags: iis, ssl, security

We are building a web application which will be need SSL to ensure data being moved around is secure.  The application's structure is:

> Web Application - WCF Service - Database

so all communicate to and from the database has to go through the WCF Service, the Web Application can not talk to the database directly.  To ensure this is secure, we need to setup SSL on both the Web Application and WCF Service.

Only my local machine, for testing purposes, I created a Self-Signed Certificate in IIS 7, using port 443 and IP address of *, so all sites should be using that 1 certificate if configured to require SSL.

Once we go to production, both the Web Application and WCF Service most likely will be on the same server, can 1 SSL certificate configured the same way work? Or will we need to create 2 certificates and configure the port and IP addresses separately for both Web Application and WCF Service?

Thanks.

Comment: if you've got multiple hostnames (e.g. host.example.com and server.example.com), you'll need 2 ssl certs (one for each host), or a wildcard cert ($$$)

Comment: A certificate is tied to a server _name_, not an IP address. Also, doesn't IIS have virtual hosts with the ability to use one certificate per virtual host? Finally, you also have wildcard certificates.

Comment: ok, so 1 will work then, as we have one hostname, something like:
www.servername/appname and for service
www.servername/service/abc.svc

Comment: You can only have different certificates on different network interfaces; the SSL protocol forces the server to present its certificate before the client announces what host it was looking for. (That's a Good Thing even if it does make multi-hosting harder.)

Answer (score 2):

Look for SAN certificates. For example [this](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm). Essentially, SAN certificates allow you to mention multiple hostnames in one certificate itself. Note that not all clients supports working with these certs. I think most if not all browser works well, Java native HTTP client works (but not Java servers )